# 2nd Linux server for images (combination with Magento)

Tags: magento, ubuntu, media

I'm working on a Magento webshop and I have two servers.
1) www.myserver.com
2) media.myserver.com

Every night the content from the server 1 media folder is copied to server 2's media folder.

So on server 2 I **only have** images (no php etc) , but I would like to speed things up :-)
What would be the correct way to do so? How can I speed things up? What kind of caching do I need.

Should I use Apache, or are there other servers only for media files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx is cited as a suitable candidate for this task. You might find this question interesting
[Nginx serving static content and proxy to apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392296/nginx-serving-static-content-and-proxy-to-apache)

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm going to try to work with G-WAN and Apache2